# Telerik Image Manager - JSON parse error when uploading images and EnableAsyncUpload is set to True

Tags: asp.net, image, telerik, radeditor

I've submitted this question to Telerik forums but haven't received any reply yet so a coworker advised to post here...

We're using `RadEditor` with `ImageManager` and `EnableAsyncUpload` property set to `true`.

When trying to upload an image (a small one btw), the upload seems to go forever and when I look at Chrome's Dev Tool console, an error is logged:

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 453

Doing this on Firefox, the message changes to:

> JSON.parse: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column
>   454 of the JSON data

(in the end, both messages points to the same issue).

Example of Chrome error message.

[Chrome error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOi3L.png)

When I change `EnableAsyncUpload` property to false, it uploads correctly and saves the image in the specified location without any problem.

I tried to debug it and saw that the problem appears when Telerik's code try to `parseJSON` a string that comes with more information than expected (highlighted in yellow). This information is added by the application and I can't change that.

[Parse JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpTrD.png)

I can leave it with `EnableAsyncUpload` in `false` but it kinda bugs me.

Is it really ok leaving `EnableAsyncUpload` in `false`? Is there a way to fix this issue?

Code is like this:

```
<div id="HtmlBodyCell" style="<%= HtmlBodyCellStyle %>">
 <Telerik:RadEditor ID="HtmlBodyTextArea" runat="server" Width="475px" Height="400px" />
</div>
```

```
HtmlBodyTextArea.EnableFilter(Telerik.Web.UI.EditorFilters.MakeUrlsAbsolute);           
HtmlBodyTextArea.ImageManager.UploadPaths = imgPath;
HtmlBodyTextArea.ImageManager.ViewPaths = imgPath;
HtmlBodyTextArea.ImageManager.MaxUploadFileSize = 200000;
HtmlBodyTextArea.ImageManager.EnableAsyncUpload = true;
HtmlBodyTextArea.ImageManager.RenderMode = RenderMode.Lightweight;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The case was researched at https://www.telerik.com/forums/image-manager---json-parse-error-when-uploading-images-and-image-manager-has-enableasyncupload-set-to-true.

What Gaby did to resolve it was to add a condition to the generation of the additional entry, like  the Request.FilePath should not contain "Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd".